# Questions about a simple proof technique

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have a question about a type of proof.

I think an example might be helpful. For example, I need to prove that if a**v**=$0$, then either a=$0$ or v=$0$. Some proofs are: if a$\ne$$0$, then blah blah blah .. v=$0$. My question is that, by proving like that, how can you show that the complete conclusion is “if a**v**=$0$, then either a=$0$ or v=$0$” but not “if a**v**=0, then v=$0$”? Because after assuming a$\ne$$0$, one use the assumption later in proving v=$0$?

Shouldn’t we illustrate an example of “a=$0$, v$\ne$$0$“ to show the completeness of the conclusion?

Maybe when we try to prove it, we assume the conclusion is complete by default?

I hope my expression is clear. I am really confused with the if A, then B or C proof.

Comment: "$P$ or $Q$" is logically equivalent, as a matter of propositional logic, to "if not $P$, then $Q$" (and also to "if not $Q$, then $P$").

Answer (score 2):

To prove a statement, we do not have the establish that the conclusion is the best possible.  When we prove that A implies (B or C), it could very well be that A implies C by itself.  There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thank you, it perfectly solves my question. I think it’s who writes the problem that needs to consider whether the conclusion is the best?

Answer (score 0):

> If $A$ then $B$ or $C$.
>
> *Proof*: Surely, one of $B$ or $\neg B$ is true. So, if we assume that $B$ is true, then it follows that the conclusion is true. On the other hand, if we assume that $\neg B$ is true and, in some way, we prove that $C$ is true using $\neg B$, then, again, the conclusion is true.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a question about they way mathematicians use the word 'OR'. In conversational English using or in a statement like this does often imply that both options are possible, but that's a fuzzy and imprecise method relying on what hasn't been said, and so isn't suited to strictly formal maths.

In mathematics, the statement 'False OR True' is true. That's the case even though it's always the 'True' option that's true and never the 'False' option. As such, the statement 'A implies C' is included in 'A implies (B or C)': whenever the first is true so will the latter. And it's perfectly fine to stop a proof at a weaker statement.

To demonstrate why mathematicians treat 'OR' like this, let me expand on the example you gave. I'll fill out the implied parts of the statement to make it, 'For all numbers $a$ and vectors $\mathbf{v}$ such that $a \mathbf{v} = 0$, either $a=0$ or $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$.' What we'd like to be able to do, with a 'For all' statement like this, is substitute in particular values and still have the statement be true. That is, since the statement is true 'For all $a$ and $\mathbf{v}$', it ought to be true for any particular values we choose.

So let's try that, with... let's say... the values $a=4$ and $\mathbf{v} = (0,0,0)$. These are values such that $a \mathbf{v} = 0$ so the statement should apply. So we substitute them in to get the statement, 'Either $4=0$ or $(0,0,0) = \mathbf{0}$'. Is this statement true?

If you accept that an OR statement can be true when only one of its options is true, then we're fine: the option '$(0,0,0) = \mathbf{0}$' is true, so the OR statement is true. But if you require examples from both sides of the OR statement, then you're in trouble: there's no way we're going to be able to illustrate an example of '$4=0$'. But that would mean that, somehow, the 'For all' statement was true while (most) instances of it aren't true.

And that's why mathematicians prefer to treat OR the way we do.